# Getting last inserted ID to put in a text box (c# windows)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, textbox

I ask for help to do the following:

I make an insert via a procedure. After saving I want to fill the textbox with the ID created, so I can use it to associate with my item

[image]

I just need the order code to enter into the text box.

"New" button click event:

```
 private void btnNovoPedido_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         int codigoCli = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodCliente.Text);
         DateTime dtIni = DateTime.Now;
         int idCliente = int.Parse(txtCodCliente.Text);
         cc.pInserirPedido(0, dtIni, null, idCliente); // proc for add new order
         MessageBox.Show("Pedido gerado" );

         for (int i = 0; i < dgvItemPedido.RowCount; i++)
         {
             dgvItemPedido.Rows[i].DataGridView.Columns.Clear();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Comment: Even if this is only just tentative code, make it your habit to apply separation of concerns  from the outset. You should be able to reproduce (and explain) the problem without any reference to WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store procedure you should add in the last line return @@identity
Then in your code you can read the value

Comment: I found the solution with. txtIDPedido.Text = cc.TB_PEDIDOs.Max(x => x.ID_PEDIDO).ToString();. Simple, thank all guys.

Comment: @Jameson - selecting the Max() will not work in cases of concurrency.

Comment: lol,  I tring use @@identity,  more I'm not know implant in my code

Comment: How are you calling your store procedure? If you use a command the result should be the @@identity value